# old projects work fine but can't make a new one

Tags: android, android-studio

on my Mac I can open my previous projects but can't make a new project because I keep facing these issues, I've tried cleaning project and android studio cashes but nothing works:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: runtime
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: viewmodel
Affected Modules: app


ERROR: Failed to resolve: livedata-core
Affected Modules: app
```

my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: @Steven I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Migrating Android to Android X by clicking Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

Try **File>Settings>Build and Deployment>** unchecked **OFFLINE WORK**